# bootstrap calendar not displaying although everything is fine

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am using the datepicker of bootstrape

```
<input type="text" style="height: 30px ! important;" value="05/16/2014" onclick="$(this).datepicker();" name="tododate" placeholder="Date" id="tododate1" size="16" class="m-wrap m-ctrl-medium date-picker hasDatepicker">
```

the input display on button click

Comment: Do you have a live example?

Comment: no. if i put it outside of my project code its works.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a conflict with your javascript files.

Try this:

```
<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
//put the above just before the input below
<input type="text" style="height: 30px ! important;" value="05/16/2014" onclick="$j(this).datepicker();" name="tododate" placeholder="Date" id="tododate1" size="16" class="m-wrap m-ctrl-medium date-picker hasDatepicker">
```

Note the `onclick="$j(this).datepicker();"` ($j)

More about `jQuery.noConflict();` http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/
Hope this helps!